# Tensorflow Inception FeedInputs: unable to find feed output input

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-recognition

I tried the inception tutorial in tensorflow site:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/image_retraining/
the bazel build is done successfully but when I try to predict an image class wth this command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg
```

I have this error: 
tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:305] Running model failed: Not found: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output input

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2883#issuecomment-226591095) helped me to fix this issue.

It seems that we need to provide `--input_layer` with Tensorflow 1.0+.

In your case, this should fix the problem:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image \
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result \
--image=$HOME/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg \
--input_layer=Mul
```

Comment: THank you for your answer, I will try this solution tonight

Comment: Great, It works thanks. Else is it normal to have a lot of c++ compilation error messages even though I have a correct answer in the end?

Comment: This is some warnings from `core`, it doesn't prevent to compile it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can some please add this to the tensor flow documentation? That would be a great help for others.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Tensorflow 1.0+? I had the same issue but switching over to an earlier version (I used 0.12.0) resolved the issue. It must be something in the 1.0.0 update that broke the tutorial

Comment: Yes I have the last version of Tensorflow. I cloned the repo the last week so I think it is the 1.0+ version of Tensorflow. I will try to clone an older version of tensorflow

Comment: I switched to an older version of tensorflow 0.12.0 but I had a problem building the retrain with bazel. May be I have to build it without bazel ?

Comment: I didn't have any problems with using bazel with tensorflow 0.12.0. But also running the commands without bazel still works for me