# Tensorflow fails to build image_retraining:label_image

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I have compiled TensorFlow with AVX and SSE (cloned from git repository). Hello TensorFlow script works and doesnt print the warning that the CPU supports instructions the binary wasnt compiled for.

Later I have created directories with images and ran the retrainer:

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/mydata
```

But when I try to build label_image, I get this error:

```
bazel build --config=opt tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:label_image
ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:label_image': no such target '//tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:label_image': target 'label_image' not declared in package 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining' defined by /home/user/myretraining/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/BUILD
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such target '//tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:label_image': target 'label_image' not declared in package 'tensorflow/examples/image_retraining' defined by /home/user/myretraining/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/BUILD
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.118s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)

(/home/user/myretraining is the source dir root)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I compile label_image?

Comment: I had same issue this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022516/tensorflow-inception-feedinputs-unable-to-find-feed-output-input) by **vbonnet** worked for me.

Comment: @ZeeshanShahid Thanks, but the answer there talks about running label_image, while I can't even compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your **label_image.py** is not in this directory tensorflow/examples/image_retraining, In my case it was in tensorflow/examples/label_image this folder. so try

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This was it, looks like the guide on google's site needs to be updated!